# Use of to in the sentence- "to the unspeakable relief of the student ..."

Tags: sentence-structure, prepositional-phrases, adverbial-phrases

Why *to* is used here:

> tuberculosis,bad tonsils,sleeping sickness, poor digestion,various forms of mental and nervous difficulty have been brought to light by the doctor during the past few months,***to*** the unspeakable relief of the student and enlightenment of faculty.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's a prepositional phrase which conveys a sense of cause and effect. In your example, we can reword your sentence as:

> There was unspeakable relief of the student and enlightenment of faculty ***after*** tuberculosis,bad tonsils,sleeping sickness, poor digestion,various forms of mental and nervous difficulty was brought to light by the doctor during the past few months.

In other words, the doctor's act or investigation made students feel a sigh of relief. However, I would like to know more about the context and who was suffering those maladies.

It terms of that *to*, it's common to use such phrases when talking about feeling. For instance,

> To my surprise, he didn't bring my book.

This simply means that I got surprised when I found that he didn't bring the book.